# Components not re render on state change

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update a state of a list. And need to rerender the list as per the `ids` state. But array takes reference value and everytime I update the `ids` with `setIds`, I am unable to get the updated list as the component is not rerendered. Anyway to achieve this. I have tried adding `const [idsLength, setIdsLength] = useState(0)` and passing and updating it in the list. But I feel there is a better approach for this.

```
const Component1 = () => {
  const [ids, setIds] = useState([]);
  
  const handleIdClick = () => {
    const temp = ids
    temp.push(ids.length)
    setIds(temp)
    console.log(ids)
  }
  
  return(
    <div>
        <div onClick={handleIdClick}>
            Id Adder
        </div>
        {ids.map(id=>{
            return(
                <div key={id}>
                    {id}
                </div>
            )
        })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use `useEffect` hook

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("ids :" + ids);
  }, [ids]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create and pass in a new array with updated contents to `setIds`

```
const handleIdClick = useCallback(() => {
    setIds([...ids, ids.length]);
}, [ids])
```